# Typescript DeepPartial/Partial без undefined

Tags: typescript

У меня есть тип `testType`:

```typescript
type testType =
    {
        property1: string;
        objectProperty:
        {
            test0: number;
            test1: boolean;
            test2: string;
        };
    };
```

И я хочу получить тип, в котором все свойства объекта будут не обязательные. Т. к. обычный `Partial` нам не подходит из-за вложенного объекта, я нашел `DeepPartial`:

```typescript
type DeepPartial<T> = T extends object ?
    {
        [ P in keyof T ]?: DeepPartial<T[ P ]>;
    } : T;
```

В итоге мы получаем код:

```typescript
export type DeepPartial<T> = T extends object ?
    {
        [ P in keyof T ]?: DeepPartial<T[ P ]>;
    } : T;

type testType =
    {
        property1: string;
        objectProperty:
        {
            test0: number;
            test1: boolean;
            test2: string;
        };
    };

type testTypePartial = DeepPartial<testType>;
/*
{
    property1?: string | undefined;
    objectProperty?: 
    {
        test0?: number | undefined;
        test1?: boolean | undefined;
        test2?: string | undefined;
    } | undefined;
} 
*/
```

---

Но тут я осознаю, что я смогу передать свойство со значение `undefined`, но мне этого не нужно. Мне скорее нужно получить объект, где должно быть свойство с изначальным типом либо его вообще не должно быть. Как это можно реализовать?

И я так понимаю, что получится очень много перечислений типов, что не есть хорошо.
Я ожидаю следущее:

```typescript
// Правильно
const test0: testTypePartial =
{
    property1: "value"
};

// Неправильно
const test1: testTypePartial =
{
    property1: undefined  // Тип "undefined" не может быть назначен для типа "string". ts(2322)
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо в настройках тайпскрипта (`tsconfig.json`) включить [`exactOptionalPropertyTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exactOptionalPropertyTypes).

[Playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAixhgAoENYCWuANgDwAqAfHALxzlygzAB2AJgM5wQBGAVsADG8APxwA3gCg4cANrY4BFnADWwRBABm9ALoiAXOkw58MImXLydlANySAvnEPk7kpCnrAOMcslR0pGTAoCBRYRABGQ28oJQBzOxleAWFsELCkQ0CZBC8YAAZDFgBXAFseYChEnOZvKLgeCAhiYFwWaplamAAmaJhYlgTpOHs7Uck3P09vXxQ8QhJaIyx5sxIKPNngW0kgA)

Comment: Можно ли это включить для отдельного файла? Это вызвало очень много проблем по всему проекту, и даже там, где я не ожидаю видеть ошибку.

Comment: @OliverPatterson, не знаю. Если есть что-то отдельным пакетом, то думаю можно. А именно для файла или папки - сомнительно, хотя может isolatedModules могут как-то помочь, но не знаю. Мне кажется, проще типы поправить по проекту.

Comment: Когда я включил данную настройку, у меня были ошибки по проекту и в частности по MUI, что меня огорчило.